# Configure port forwarding with interface command within VRF

Tags: nat, cisco-ios-15

We are working with VRFs and having a look into the NVI NAT configuration. Without VRFs, we can configure following:

```
ip nat source static tcp 10.0.0.2 80 interface Dialer1 80
ip nat source static tcp 10.0.0.3 80 interface Dialer1 8080
```

I can use the WAN interface and dont have to update the configuration in case, the WAN IP changes. But if I use the interface, i cant define a VRF anymore:

```
roTST02(config)#ip nat source static tcp 10.0.0.2 80 interface Dialer1 80 ?
  <cr>
```

If i use the WAN IP, i can set a vrf:

```
roTST02(config)#ip nat source static tcp 10.0.0.2 80 4.4.4.4 80 ?         
  extendable  Extend this translation when used
  no-alias    Do not create an alias for the global address
  no-payload  No translation of embedded address/port in the payload
  vrf         Specify vrf
  <cr>
```

Is there a soluiton for that? Using VRFs should not limit the NAT possibilities from my point of view. Tested on IOS 15.6(2)T & 15.7(3)M4a

Comment: Why you want to set both interface and VRF? Interface is always in one of VRFs thus setting interface means setting VRF as well. Setting VRF is needed when you use some addresses which aren't known to belong to any VRF thus you can set explicit VRF.

Comment: I tested setting just the interface. Although It creates a dynamic NAT entry in the correct VRF when traffic is passing from the WAN interface with the correct port, the session times out from the initiator. Debugging on the client indicates, that the traffic does never reach the client at all.